# SQL Server : grouping results

Tags: sql-server, aggregation

I need to separate a result set based on the content of a row, every time this row has the code 110 it means that it started a new group.

This row is the code of service status, I'm controlling each time my client received an answer, if the client returns with following questions, the table receives a new record with the code 110.

I tried using the LAG function, but couldn't get what I need exactly, I also some workaround with row_number using partitions, but couldn't get what I need.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Edit:

Example data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WUcg5A0r6LGvXC9UOdjG9YUtxG2L47od8H9cX8MgaFQ/edit?usp=sharing

I need to create a Internal group on this data, every time the internal code is 110, I need to increase the group number, like the Internal Group column on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this is very unclear. Please post some sample data and the desired result. Also tag your question with the version of SQL Server that you are using

Comment: post some sample data and the desired outcome than we might be able to help you

Comment: I added more information, I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    d.[Start date],
    d.[final date],
    d.[Situation],
    d.[Reason for client reopening],
    d.[Call time],
    d.[Total time],
    d.[Internal Code],
    d.[SLA time],
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN d.[Internal Code] = 110 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) OVER (
        ORDER BY
            d.[Start date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    dbo.ExampleData d;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you Bruce Dunwiddie, I really appreciate it